# Php function to encode tabs etc to html

Tags: php, escaping

I'm looking for a function that encodes spaces, tabs etc into html characters

Eg take the collection of strings:

```
        Whats up?&^5@#
number  pie     word
1       3       hi
2       4       no
```

which I process:

```
$outString="";
for($i=0;$i<count($strArr);$i++){
    $outString.= somefunc($strArr[$i]);//what should somefunc be?
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace spaces (etc.) into a character of your choice?

Comment: What's a tab char in HTML? What is this for? What are you ultimately doing with `$outString`?

Comment: Its a pre-formatted string, with somewhat random, formatting ( including arbitrary tab spacing to generate tables. Currently I use `<pre>` tags, but I am trying to move away from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you seen [html entities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [html special chars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) ?

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't have any means of representing a tab stop, so this isn't achievable per se.

You could wrap the content in a `<pre>` element, but this would be better addressed by `explode`ing each line on tab characters, and then generating a `<table>` from the resulting data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to create tabs in html, but if you change all to html table, you should be ok. Try something like this:

```
function foo($string) {
    $table='<table border="0">'.htmlentities($string).'</table>';
    $table=preg_replace( "#\r\n#", "</td></tr><tr><td>", $table);
    $table=preg_replace( "#\t#", "</td><td>", $table);

    return $table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how to convert tabs within a string into a table..

```
<?php
$string="heres a random string


table here:
nice\t nice2\tnice3 
    
then more text continuing here.. yep..\tbut this 1 tab?";

echo addTablesToString($string);
function addTablesToString($string){
    $lines = explode("\n", $string);
    $in_table = 0;
    foreach ($lines as $k => $line) {
        if (substr_count($line, "\t") > 1) {
            $table = "";
            if (!$in_table) {
                $in_table = 1;
                $table = "<table>";
            }
            $lines[$k] = "$table<tr><td>" . str_replace("\t", "</td><td>", $line) . "</td></tr>";
        } elseif ($in_table) {
            $lines[$k] = "</table>" . $line;
            $in_table = 0;
        }
    }
    if ($in_table) 
        $lines[$k] .= "</table>";
    return implode("\n", $lines);
}
```